# How I can add a heat map or Fader extension to my forge viewer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, iot, autodesk-forge

Actually, I'm devlopping an application of BIM-Sensors integration.
I get the values of sensors at each timestamp as markups in viewer but I want to represent these values in some surfaces of model as gradient at each timestamp.
As shown in the picture below, I want to get something like that:
I would like to ask you for help

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All that you can possibly need for this project is doucumented by The Building Coder discussions of the [RvtFader Revit add-in](https://github.com/jeremytammik/RvtFader) and the [ForgeFader reimplementation within the Forge viewer](https://github.com/jeremytammik/forgefader).

That app is not up-to-date for the current version of Forge, so you will need to do some research yourself on how to migrate it to the current system.

All the required steps are documented in full, though, so there should be no problem adapting them appropriately.